# String Concatenation In Sql Server With Distinct Values Sorted On Diff Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following scenario,to make it brief i have created fiddle for this [Sql Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e8327/3) 
I have  case id(CaseId) for which i can have multiple subject id(CaseSubjId) & those case subject can be added any time so their insertion order is maintained by rowid."Office" column displays office location for that particular case subject.
I have to query concat all location in csv manner for each case id so that distinct values can be selected for office & concatenation order is maintained in rowid asc order.

```
CREATE TABLE TmpTest(CaseId INT,CaseSubjId INT,Office VARCHAR(10),RowId INT) 
INSERT INTO TmpTest(CaseId,CaseSubjId,Office,RowId)VALUES 
(1,1,'Kol',1),(1,2,'Del',2),(1,3,'Kol',4),(1,4,'Noi',3),(1,5,'Kol',6),
(1,6,'Bhu',7),(2,11,'Kol',5),(2,12,'Bhu',3),(2,13,'Kol',4),(2,14,'Met',7),
(2,15,'Bhu',1),(2,16,'Met',2) 
--OutPut Required:

       CaseId | Office
       1      | Kol,Del,Noi,Bhu
       2      | Bhu,Met,Kol 

--Order By Row Id Asc Group By Case Id Concat String In CSV For Office Value
```

But Output i am getting all values in office getting concatenated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
select distinct caseid,
STUFF(
           (SELECT    DISTINCT  ',' + tmp.Office
           FROM      TmpTest AS tmp
           WHERE      tmp.CaseId = TmpTest.CaseId
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
AS Locations 
from TmpTest group by caseid
```